# Text not horizontally centre in nav bar / Too much space between nav bar text

Tags: html, css, hover, navbar, spacing

Here I have my website: http://gyazo.com/56e069ebf8b5bd61ee30523886180b88

There are a number of issues with the nav bar.

1.You can see that the text or nav bar is not horizontally centered, as indicated by the hover (which is equal on top and bottom)

2.There is to much space in between the text, (and this spacing is the only way I've found works without the text moving around when highlighting or hovering.

So for 1. is there a way I can make the text or the nav bar (not sure what is the cause) centre so the hover looks more equal (horizontally)

For 2. Is there a way I can close the gap between the text, while still keeping the same padding settings, and so it doesn't move the text around when I use the hover function.

I've also added a jsfiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/d1a5eshs/

HTML FOR NAV BAR

```
<!--TOP NAV BAR SECTION-->
            <div id="nav_bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>

                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="survival.html">SURVIVAL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><br><a href="pure-pvp.html">PURE-PVP</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><br><a href="gamesworld.html">GAMESWORLD</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>

                    </li>
                </ul
```

CSS FOR NAV BAR

```
/*TOP NAV BAR SECTION*/
#nav_bar {
    background-color: #a22b2f;
    padding:1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 
    height:45px;
    }         
#nav_bar ul li {
    display: inline-block;    
}
#nav_bar ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    padding-top:17px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}
#nav_bar ul li ul {
    display: none;   
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#8c1b1f;
    padding-bottom:13px;
    padding-top:13px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;   
}
#nav_bar>ul>li>ul>li>a:hover {
    background:#c9c9c9;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;      
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:5px;
}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;

}
#nav_bar ul li:hover ul li a {
    color: black;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bol;
    margin-left:-20px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were several spacing issues and also there were several `duplicate styles` and a few mistakes, but I think I fixed all your issues. http://jsfiddle.net/d1a5eshs/1/.

Comment: Thats seems to work well, however the text is still spaced apart, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my version of your navigation bar: http://jsfiddle.net/zo541am2/.  I trimmed and simplified both your HTML and CSS code.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="status.html">STATUS</a></li>
        <li><a href="info.html">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GAMEMODES</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="survival.html">SURVIVAL</a></li>
                <li><a href="pure-pvp.html">PURE-PVP</a></li>
                <li><a href="gamesworld.html">GAMESWORLD</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="rules.html">RULES</a></li>
        <li><a href="vote.html">VOTE</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

nav {
    background-color: #a22b2f;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav > ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 650px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: bold 15px/3 Serif;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #e2e2e2;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a {
    background: #8c1b1f;
}

nav ul ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font: bold 12px/3 Sans-Serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul ul > li:hover > a {
    background: #c9c9c9;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```